# I have installed pandas but cannot import in VScode

Tags: python, pandas, pip

My lap is MacBookPro2017, macOS Mojave 10.14.16

I used to coding in Jupyter and everything goes well.

However when I want to do the same thing in VScode, it said that

**"ImportError: No module named pandas"**

I am sure I have installed pandas by

```
pip3 install pandas
```

---

I do following things:

1.Search for similar problems on SO, and someone says there may be more than one version python, the pip and pandas may under another path. Then I find there are python2.7 and python3.7 in my lap:

```
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ which python
/usr/bin/python
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ which pandas
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ pandas --version
-bash: pandas: command not found
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ pip --version
pip 19.2.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

And if I type:

```
AlfiedeMacBook-Pro:~ alfie$ pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.12.0)
```

So I think I have pandas in the true path(?)

2.Then I saw some one use **sys** to append the path, so I write it in front of my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Then I got:

**ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.13.3**

**your numpy version is 1.8.0rc1.**

**Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.13.3 to use this pandas version**

But my numpy version is 1.17, I have upgraded.

So I just want know what I should do to make the pandas can be used in VScode?

Comment: can you import successfully from the terminal python3.7 execution?

Comment: I can import successful when using the terminal. And I can see there are three versions python when I choose execution in VScode. I tried each of them but none works.

Comment: An easy workaround is to create an `virtualenv` environment. Then install `pandas` again. Last step is to set VScode python interpreter as your `virtualenv`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. The problem was that VS Code was using a different environment (shown in the lower left corner). Switching the environment there solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to change the Kernel in the upper right corner in case that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For beginner:
The answer kinda was given above, but I took a long time to find the exact solution.

1. First thing, that this really happen because of the Environment that will be the responsible to interpret your Python code and properly run it (*you can run even in the wrong environment, but it'll not take the result you want*)
2. To fix it in the best way:
3. Find the version of your Python, typing `python --version` if it doesn't work type `python3 --version``
4. Then after see the version - I'll consider as Python 3 - you'll type `python3 -m venv venv` this will create a virtual environment what is the recommended way to deal with your projects. *A important reminder, it'll create the environment in the current folder that you're with your project*
5. Finally, you can activate it by typing `. venv/bin/activate` will activate your project. *For some systems you don't even need to do it, but for me was necessary*
6. Then you go to your terminal in VS Code, open python and find where this environment is executing the follow commands:
   `python3`
   `import sys`
   `print(sys.executable)`
7. Copy the folder path. Then click in the lower left corner of your VS Code *(it'll be written 'interpreter' or 'Python 2.x.x' or 'Python 3.x.x'* (you got, right), then choose it, upper above will ask for you to choose a path to your interpreter and you paste the path you copied in the path 6.
8. Finally now, install all the paths normally with `pip install module`

I hope it'll work for you peeps! I finally got my program working from here.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. My Python version in VS Code was same as Terminal. Same environment. Same `sys.executable` path. But the `PATH` in `os.environ` found in `command prompt/spyder Console/Jupyter terminal` was different compared to the `PATH` I got from VS Code terminal.

VS Code starts `PATH` like this from `os.environ['PATH']`:

```
'PATH': 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;...'`
```

And terminal starts `PATH` like this  from `os.environ['PATH']`:

```
'PATH': 'C:\\Users\\userid\\Appdata\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3;...'
```

So when I replaced the `PATH` variable to start with my anaconda path, Import pandas worked fine.

Though Anaconda Path was present in VS Code `PATH` variables also, it was at the end. So I guess it was changed by VS Code in startup.

Answer (score 0):

Having that problem while being in a properly set up environment, the first you should do is to close all vscode windows and then start it fresh.

I've stumbled on that today and it has worked.